# How can I move the potion explosion ingredient dispenser?

Tags: components, potion-explosion

When I play Potion Explosion, I want to turn the ingredient (marble) dispenser so the current player can easily see it and choose ingredients. But when I lift it, it comes apart.  I have tried gripping it from the lowest supports, but pieces still come off, marbles go everywhere, and they don't end up in the same place they were at the end of the last player's turn.

Is there a good way to pick up the dispenser and move it without it falling apart? Does glue help?  What kind of glue should be applied, and where?

Comment: Will it fit back in the box while assembled? If so, I'd use wood glue or liquid nails. Otherwise, get a small Lazy Susan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Gluing the joints with common Elmer's Glue makes the dispenser sturdy enough to move about when filled with marbles.

[image: Filled Finished Dispenser]

Assembled without glue, the dispenser tends to come apart:

[image: Unglued Empty Dispenser]

Empty the dispenser and turn it over.

[image: Unglued Dispenser Underside]

Apply glue to everywhere the supports cross each other.  I didn't put glue anywhere it would be visible from the outside:

[image: Glued Joints Near Front]
[image: Glued Joints Near Rear]

After drying overnight, it can be filled and moved about without any trouble.  It fits into the storage box that comes with the game.

Answer (score 1):

I use a lazy susan (turntable) beneath mine.